# How can I access the define macro in the header file from other files with Conditional Compilation?

Tags: c++

I have a macro in a header file:

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#define vulkan

#endif
```

I want to use this macro with `#ifdef` from other headers and sources files.

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "header.h"

#ifdef vulkan
//use vulkan api
#else
//use opengl api
#endif

#endif
```

I also want to use `#ifdef` in the `game.cpp` source file, but I can't reach the `vulkan` macro with `#ifdef`, neither from the header nor from the source. What is the right way to do this?

**EDIT**: I am uploading pictures:

header.h

[image]

game.h

[image]

game.cpp

[image]

**EDIT 2**: minimal reproducible example:

header.h

[image]

game.h

[image]

game.cpp

[image]

main.cpp

[image]

**EDIT 3**: here is the code:

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#define macro

#endif
```

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "header.h"

class game
{
public:


    #ifdef macro
    int test;
    #else
    int test;
    #endif



    void init();
};

#endif
```

game.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "game.h"

void game::init()
{
    #ifdef macro
    int test;
    #else
    int test;
    #endif
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "game.h"

int main()
{
    game g;

    g.init();
}
```

Comment: What you have shown is correct, and `#ifdef vulkan` should work just fine in `game.h`, and in `game.cpp` if it has `#include "game.h"` (which it should). However, your `vulkan` define would be better suited as a project-level define rather than a header-level define. Check the documentation for your compiler on how to create such defines globally in your project's makefile.

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error code. This would help us understand the problem better. Otherwise the code should work.

Comment: #ifdef does not compile even though I have defined vulkan in header file. always the else part is compiled.

Comment: You've told us what you *think* is happening.   That doesn't work since, if you don't know the cause of your problem, what you think is happening is probably wrong so you will have omitted relevant details.   To give other people a fighting chance of helping you, you need to provide a [mcve] - a SMALL but COMPLETE sample of ACTUAL code that others can use to recreate your problem.

Comment: i am not saying what i am thinking. i am just trying to find problem. i add pictures maybe it can be give more detail.

Comment: i did minimal reproducible example and uploaded pictures can you check.

Comment: The only anomaly I can see is that your `game::init()` function - in the code you posted, not the image -defines variables named `test` that have the same name as the members of the class `game`.     So you have a scoping problem (changes to the variable named `test` inside `game::init()` do not affect the member of the class `game` named `test`).    In other words, your problem has NOTHING to do with macros, and is related to your lack of understanding of scoping of variables in C++.

Comment: i noticed now yes i made redeclaration mistake there. but i found problem. code working right but my ide showed faded compiled part.

Comment: @luffy given the code you have shown, and the symptoms you have described, you likely have at least 2 copies of `header(s).h` on your machine, where 1 copy is defining the macro, and 1 copy is not, and sometimes the compiler is finding 1 copy vs the other. Try adding a `#pragma message` statement to the copy that defines the macro, and make sure that *every* translation unit you compile actually displays that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i also want to use #ifdef in game.cpp source ... What is right way ?

This is a right way:

```
// game.cpp
#include "header.h"
```

If "header.h" defines a macro, then including it will bring the macro definition to the translation unit.

Comment: but i can't reach vulkan macro with #ifdef neither from the header nor from the source. always the else part is compiled.

Comment: @luffy It works. Look here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/bZYJUBufhFU9ZLkH

Comment: you are right but i add pictures my compiler look main message

Comment: @luffy Create a [mcve]

Comment: i did can you look again

Comment: @luffy Don't post images. Post the code.

Comment: i added. under edit 3

Comment: @luffy Problem with your example is that it cannot be actually used to verify whether the macro is defined. It behaves the same whether the macro is defined or not. I've expanded it a bit to make it verifiable, and it works just fine here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/btA6tZNimQwACTEx

Comment: you are right. I noticed that the part that says faded is compiled. this misled me. sorry for bothering you.